# How to calculate network Load in omnet++ using INET framework

Tags: omnet++

I am simulating a datacenter in OMNET++ using INET Framework, I want to calculate network load at individual links/switches/routers, how can i do this

Answer (score 1):

- Just measure the received/sent bytes on each link. Knowing the speed of the link + the time passed you can calculate the average utilization on that link.
- INET does not contain a model for CPU utilization so you cannot measure switch/router utilization by default, but you can watch the queue length on the output network interfaces and you can calculate an average queue length.

OMNeT++/INET automatically gathers these statistics in the scalar and vector result files.